# How to get the mp3 title,Image and description from a url using exoplayer

Tags: firebase, android-studio, firebase-storage, exoplayer, exoplayer2.x

Currently, I'm building an Android music streaming app using Exoplayer library. Now I'm trying to set

> PlayerNotificationManager.MediaDescriptionAdapter()

and I want to get the song title, artist name, and image of the mp3 which is stored in the firebase storage.
therefore I'm using the mp3 URL to stream. My question is how to get mp3 metadata like artist name, song title, and image that originally stored by the owner of the music.